# Bend Mesh Over Other Mesh

Tags: modeling, objects

Could you give me an advice how to bend mesh #1 over the mesh #2. I use Blender 2.79.

For the other bend, where the target surface was straight, I used a *Lattice* modifier, but in this case it wouldn't work well.
I need your expert advice here!

[image]

Comment: what about the shrinkwrap modifier?

Comment: I used ShrinkWrap mod, but it deform the mesh #1 beyond recognition. And no Shrinkwrap settings could help.